# What is a MUST before handing in my notice for a contract job?

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom

I always had been a permanent employee.

I had been offered a contract a few days ago... they want me to start in a week...

I know that with permanent positions, I need written offer from new employer before handing over my notice...

***What is a must for a contract position before handing over notice to current employer ?***

added information: I am not sure what the standard practice is, they only told me on phone at the present that they liked me after a interview and want to proceed

Comment: Do you have the contract? and have you read it, understood it, signed it and returned it?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I am not sure what the standard practice is, they only told me on phone at the present that they liked me after a interview and want to proceed

Comment: Also look up what your notice period is for your current job. That decides whether you can actually start in a week or not

Comment: @user180146 its not a problem, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure what the standard practice is, they only told me on
>   phone at the present that they liked me after a interview and want to
>   proceed

You are now almost ready to proceed to the negotiation phase. Once you get their contract offer, you will need to read it, and maybe even run this by the person giving you legal advice. You also may need to run this by the person giving you tax advice.

Issues besides the rate they will allow you to charge could include: the delay between billing and them paying you, required deliverables, work location, maximum and minimum hours...

But because you haven't even seen the contract, let alone evaluated the contract, you are not ready to tell your current employer that your are quitting.

Comment: +1, I just received a draft copy of contract, but it's from the agency, in the start of contract is says, they can't fully gaurantee the terms and condition in this contract are fully reflective to terms and conditions they negotiated with there client, means there draft means nothing ? lol

Comment: @Mathematics Basically, yeah. What's binding is a contract signed by all parties (them, and you). A draft is not binding at all, but is expected to be a work in progress towards something that's acceptable to both you and your client.